# Is there a routing solution for PostGIS that supports Theta Star?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have a data set with 10m of accuracy. I have drones with a GPS that provides far finer resolution. I would like to provide pathing for my drone that exceeds the 10m of accuracy.

I believe theta star could do that. Is there a solution for something like `pg_routing` that supports theta star?

Answer (score 2):

pgRouting's functions require a network topology. If [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta*) is the algorithm you're speaking about, then I assume you want to route on a grid, which pgRouting does not support.

In case you can apply your use case to a network model, then I would assume that other shortest path functions would also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the graph, the data that pgRouting functions need:
id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost

For example if you have have a "triangle"

- edges are 1:1-2, 2:2-3, 3:3-2,
- Nodes are 1,2,3, edges **id** are 1,2,3 (before the colon)

For example, for edge 1, source is **1**, target is **2**

Give them a cost/reverse_cost and you can use a pgRouting function to generate your route.

If you need to match a geometry to a graph, first create the geometry using PostGIS functions, then use the pgRouting's topology functions to create a routing topology based on a geometry, that will generate the columns needed for using pgRouting's functions.